# Inconsistent pandas datetime conversion of csv file when sent trigger from S3

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, datetime, amazon-s3

I have a lambda function which is triggered by an S3 PUT or multi-part upload.  I have four csv files which all have the same format, with the date field formatted as a string.  The lambda  reads the file using pd.read_csv() and then using pd.to_datetime() to convert the string to a datetime.

On the first go, one of the files succeeded, the other three failed with an error on the date conversion.  I uploaded the three that failed, and this time one of those succeeded but two still failed, still on the datetime conversion.  So one of the files succeeded one time and failed the other.  Then I tried the two files that failed again, and one succeeded the one still failed.

I did notice that the the original file that succeeded was smallest (<100K) the one that failed and then succeeded was a bit bigger, and the two that failed the second times were larger.  But none of them are large and this lambda has handled much larger files.

I have downloaded the files and converted the strings using pd.to_datetime() locally using the exact same version of pandas (1.5.3) with no error.

I've looked at the details of the two events from the file that failed and then succeeded and see no significant difference in the event, i.e. the size of the file is identical.

I am at a loss.  What could be going on?

My function to convert to datetimes looks like this:

```
    def __convert_text_dates(self):
        for source_field in self.configuration.source_fields:
            if source_field.datatype in [Datatype.TEXT_DMY, Datatype.TEXT_MDY, Datatype.TEXT_YMD]:
                date_formats = DATE_FORMATS_MDY if source_field.datatype == Datatype.TEXT_MDY else \
                    DATE_FORMATS_DMY if source_field.datatype == Datatype.TEXT_DMY else DATE_FORMATS_YMD
                converted = False
                while not converted and date_formats:
                    try:
                        date_format = date_formats.pop()
                        self.df[source_field.name] = pd.to_datetime(self.df[source_field.name], format=date_format).\
                            astype(str).where(self.df[source_field.name].notnull(), None)
                        converted = True
                    except ValueError:
                        pass
                if not converted:
                    raise DataProcessingException(f'Unable to convert text to date in field {source_field.name}')
```

I tried uploading the same format of files and some failed and some succeeded.  Given they are all the same format I expected them all to succeed.  More oddly, one file failed once and succeeded once so I am very puzzled.

Comment: without access to those files, I don't think we can offer a whole lot